# Invalid URL (POS /v1/chat/completions) with SQL Server MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: sql-server, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I created this procedure in SQL Server to use the OpenAI API but when executing the procedure it generates error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ChatGPT_sp
(
    @api_key    varchar(500),
    @msg        nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    
    Declare @Object as Int;
    Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(4000), @status nvarchar(50), @statusText nvarchar(4000);
    Declare @ContentType nvarchar(150)
    Declare @Metodo nvarchar(15)
    Declare @Authorization nvarchar(500)    
    Declare @pv_url nvarchar(250)
    Declare @StringRequest nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @ret INT;

    --set @pv_url= 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions'
    set @pv_url= 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
    set @Metodo = 'POS'
    set @ContentType = 'application/json'
    set @Authorization = 'Bearer ' + @api_key
    --set @StringRequest = '{"model":"text-davinci-003","prompt":"' + @msg + '","max_tokens":2048,"temperature":0}'

    set @StringRequest = '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"content":"' + @msg + '","role":"user"}]}'

    print @pv_url
    print @Authorization
    print @StringRequest

    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, @Metodo, @pv_url,'false';
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @Authorization;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @ContentType;   
    --Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setOption', NULL, '2', '13056';    
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @StringRequest;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'status', @status OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;  
    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object

    print @status
    print @statusText
    print @ResponseText

    

    If @status <> '200'
    begin
        Return
    end 

    
END
GO


EXEC ChatGPT_sp 'key', 'hello'
```

Result:

> {
> "error": {
> "message": "Invalid URL (POS /v1/chat/completions)",
> "type": "invalid_request_error",
> "param": null,
> "code": null
> } }

I tried from excel using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 and the same code works correctly.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Seriously, calling APIs from within SQL Server is totally the wrong place to do it.

Comment: So why are you trying to do this inside SQL Server, using T-SQL script, instead of using an external task that's more suited to performing and managing HTTP requests and responses? Use of the sp_OA* functions is strongly discouraged because a) they tend to leak resources and compromise server stability and b) they aren't portable to Linux- or Azure-based SQL Server instances.

Comment: `set @Metodo = 'POS'` ... what method is this?